# Autocomplete from api

Tags: jquery, api, search, autocomplete

I want to make autocomplete and I have a problem with this code, I can not make it work, any help would be nice. I want select the title from the autocomplete suggestion and go to the specific URL. Thank you all.

```js
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/alljobs/", function(data) {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
      source: data,
      select: function(event, ui) {
        window.location = ui.title.rendered;
      }
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" />
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
window.location = ui.title.rendered;
```

Should be

```
window.location.href = ui.title.rendered;
```

Then it should work.

---

`window.location` returns an `object`

```js
console.log(window.location)
```

`window.location.href` returns the current *url*.

If you overwrite it using

```
window.location.href = "Your url";
```

The browser will redirect you to the new *url*

Comment: Thank you for that, however I have a problem with displaying title labels in my form,  I look everywhere and this code above should work, but currently nothing shows up!